# Target named on href links no longer seem to open in named tab (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

Perhaps it's been broken for a while, but I recently noticed named target links no longer open in the same tab.

```
<a href="www.link.com" target="name">text</a>
```

Each time the link is clicked, it now opens in a new tab, not the named tab.

I can't seem to find anything about this change, but I suppose this is a very old legacy feature that probably doesn't get a great deal of use these days.

(It still works fine in Mozilla Firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to test the code and it works fine on my side.

In my JS code, I have opened the new tab and set its name as `test_window`.

Now, when I click the link, it opens in `test_window`.

**Sample code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <script>
         
       window.open("page3.html", "test_window");
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>This is page-1</h1>
      <a href="page2.html" target="test_window">Visit Page-2 by clicking this link...</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Output in MS Edge:**

[image]

**Output in Google Chrome:**

[image]

Comment: perhaps it's only on the mac version?

Comment: @bbrodsky , I have tested the above code on the MAC machine, and I can confirm that the above code works in a same way as you could see in the above test results.

Comment: Ya, works fine on my end now too. bizarre.